# Numerical validation not accepting 0 as a number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a contact number, and would like to validate it so it is 11 digits long. I'd like it to accept `01234567891`.

I'm using a validation:

```
validates :contactNo,
          :length => {
                      :is => 11,
                      :format => { with: /[0-9]+/ },
                      :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0,
                      :message => "Contact number is not valid"
                     }
```

It doesn't accept `0` as a digit.

How would I get around this?

Comment: What column type are you using in the database? A number or a string?

Comment: I'm saving it as a integer

Comment: I don't think you say that `01234567891` as a number is 11 digits long. As a string, you may.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saving as an integer will cause `ActiveRecord` to typecast it, which will drop the leading 0, which will make the actual length 10 instead of 11. If you want leading 0's, you need to save it as a string so that `ActiveRecord` does not typecast it.

Additionally, you seem to be mixing separate validations in an incorrect way.

Probably you want this:

```
validates :contactNo,
  :length => {
    :is => 11,
    :message => "Contact number must be exactly 11 digits"
  },
  :format => {
    :with => /[0-9]+/,
    :message => "Contact number can only contain the digits 0-9"
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the above. Any suggestions how I can change the type from a integer to string. I've tried dropping the field but it won't let me as  i'm getting the following error  SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed I'm assuming its because i have my tables linked although contact number isn't being used foreign key. I tried using `rails g migration RemoveContactnoFromUser contactNo:integer`

Comment: @Nathan: Wouldn't saving **this** number as Integer cause an error *Invalid octal digit*?

Comment: @MAhmed it is probably better to ask that as a new question. Rails has mechanisms for dropping columns, creating columns, and changing existing columns.

Comment: @Nathan Thanks. I will do.

Comment: @user1934428 that's a great question. It depends on how the data is being entered. If the data is entered as a number (i.e. without using single or double quotes), you're right. But, I'm assuming the data is being entered as a string like `"01234567890"`. In that case, it's a valid string, and when Rails converts it to a number, it doesn't treat it as an octal number.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve the validation with just a regular expression by using an exact number instead of `+`

```
validates :contactNo, format: /[0-9]{11}/, message: 'must be eleven digits (0-9)'
```

But as noted by @Nathan you cannot use an integer field as 01 is typecast to 1 as an integer.